# jQuery file upload multiple instances error

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I've done file upload with jquery file upload plugin (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). But now, I'm don't know how to solve this problem: I have HTML code like this:

```
<form id="form-1"></form>
<input type="file" class="file-upload" id="file-1" name="file" form="form-1" />
<form id="form-2"></form>
<input type="file" class="file-upload" id="file-2" name="file" form="form-2" />




    $('input[type="file"][name="file"].file-upload').each(function(){
            var self = $(this);
            $(this).fileupload({
                url: window.fileUpload.uploadUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                dropZone: self,
                fileInput: self
            });
});
```

But there is problem, when I drop file over first input, it upload file 2 times - for each input. And I don't know, how to solve this problem. Do you have any solution?

EDIT:
I find out, upload is done just once, but two times is called "**fileuploaddone**" event.

SOLVED: 
jQuery file upload instance was initiated for two times over one file input.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't import jquery min-js file and write your code properly under the `<script type="text/javascript">`your code here`</script>`

Comment: What do you mean by this? I'm using jquery. I use "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js". The form I load via ajax so I call code to init fileupload when ajax is done.